# Why the Excel can't be opened with C#.net 4.0 (Sharpdevelop)

Tags: c#

I use the following code ,try to open a Exczl file with console. Why the excel can't be open but it will come to "read only".

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace crazy.Properties
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private  static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Excel.Application Xcel;
            Excel.Workbook XWbook

            Excel.Worksheet Sh1;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Xcel=new Excel.Application();
            XWbook  = Xcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            XWbook=Xcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:@"C:\Users\LD6A9D2N\Desktop\Nouveau Feuille Microsoft Excel 97-2003.xls");
            XWbook.Activate();
            Sh1 =XWbook.Application.Worksheets("Feuil1");
            Sh1.Activate();
            Sh1.Cells[1,1]=25;
            XWbook.Save();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not disposing `XWbook` and/or `Xcel`, that is why file handle is not release from your file. Thus, when you open same excel file it is opened readonly because the file has already have FileHandle on it. In other words, the file is used by another process

```
try 
{
    ....
    XWbook.Save();
    XWbook.Close(Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
    Xcel.Quit();
}
finally 
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Sh1 );
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(XWbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    Xcel= null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how I should dipose the XWbook and Xcel please ?

Comment: Thanks. and the Marshal should be which kinds of value please ?